# A button to delete multi images on one click from imagefield

Tags: media, entities

In a content type I have an image field. For the upload I use **[Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget)**. So now it is easy to upload 10 images into one field of the content type.

If I want to remove this 10 images, I have to click remove button 10 times. Is there a module which provides a single remove button to remove all images in this field on one click?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the question about "[Delete multiple images at once from one node in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144123/delete-multiple-images-at-once-from-one-node-in-drupal-7)", which appears to be similar to yours.

You may also want to look at the article about [Drupal 7 Unlimited Fields Remove Button](http://websmiths.co/blog/drupal-7-unlimited-fields-remove-button), from where you can also download the [Unlimited Fields Remove](http://websmiths.co/sites/default/files/projects/unlimitedfield_remove-7.x-0.3.zip) module.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  $found = FALSE;

  if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    $details = $element;
    $found = TRUE;
  }
  else {
    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
      if (isset($value['#field_name'])) {
        $found = TRUE;
        $details = $value;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if ($found && variable_get('MYMODULE_' . $details['#field_name'], 0) == 1) {
    $remove_button = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Remove All'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'event' => 'click',
        'callback' => 'MYMODULE_fields_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'checkboxes-div',
        'method' => 'replace',
       ),
    );
    $element['remove_button'] = $remove_button;
  }
}

function MYMODULE_fields_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $new_var = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];
  $nid = $new_var->nid;
  if(is_numeric($nid)){

    // get all fid's attached to this node
    $get_fids = db_select('file_usage', 'fu')
    ->fields('fu')
    ->condition('fu.id', $nid, '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllKeyed(0,1);

    foreach ($get_fids as $key => $value) {
      $fids[] = $key;
    }
  }

  // delete all files
  foreach ($fids as $key => $val) {
    $file = file_load($val);
    // file_usage_delete($file, 'MYMODULE');
    file_delete($file, $force = TRUE);
  }
}
```

check this .it is taken from others posted query hopefully its help for you